# How to use interpolation in tag/element names in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, interpolation

I am having trouble using interpolation string in element names while dynamically generating component selectors inside `*ngFor`. Below is my code:

```
<span *ngFor="let platform of platforms">
    <app-{{platform}}-share></app-{{platform}}-share>
</span>
```

In my component I have declared platforms property as:

```
platforms = ["one","two","three"].
```

Based on this I want to dynamically load components like:
`<app-one-share></app-one-share>` inside for loop inside view. Is there something I am missing. I get the error that

```
'app-{{platform}}-share' is not a known element:
```

Why is the interpolation value not being evaluated?

Comment: try to use ApplicationRef with this._applicationRef.tick();